# Как сохранить значение переменной после выхода из приложения

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Есть такая переменная:
 **Preferences preferences;**
В игровом классе, когда игра заканчивается делаю так:

```
  game.tempGameScore = game.dropsGatchered;
            game.dropsGatchered = 0;
            iter.remove();
            game.preferences.putInteger("Save", game.tempGameScore);
            game.preferences.flush();
```

В классе с результатом вывожу:

```
    @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(bacgTexture, 0, 0,  Drop.WIDTH, Drop.HEIGHT);
    if (game.tempGameScore != 0) {
        textFont.draw(game.batch, " " + game.preferences.getInteger("Save", game.tempGameScore),
                800/2, 480/2);
    } else {
        game.tempGameScore = 0;
        textFont.draw(game.batch, " " +  game.tempGameScore,
                800/2, 480/2);
    }
    game.batch.end();
}
```

Скорость сохраняется и выводится, как сделать, чтобы лучший результат сохранялся между сеансами?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать Shared Preferences. 
Данные будут сохраняться между сеансами

### Использование

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
}
```

Источник - [Data Storage - Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)